# Multiple queries in laravel scope function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am attempting to make multiple queries in a scope function in laravel. my code is as follows. the first query executes normally but the second seems to be ignored. what is the correct way to do this?

```
public function scopeUpdateStatus($query,$oldUser, $newUser, $alias, $env) {

$query->where('db_conn_app_alias_user', $newUser)->where('db_conn_app_alias', $alias)->where('app_instance_environment', $env)->update(array('user_status' => 'active'));
$query->where('db_conn_app_alias_user', $oldUser)->where('db_conn_app_alias', $alias)->where('app_instance_environment', $env)->update(array('user_status' => 'passive'));

return "success";
}
```

Comment: do you have "success" returned ?

Comment: yes the first query executes just not the second, there is no issues accessing the function

Comment: hm,strange try to trace calls with debugger.

Comment: I changed the query to use DB::update and now it works....i wonder what the issue is here

Comment: great - I am thinking that returned result from update is messing something.

Comment: Why you just don't call it twice passing first the `$newUser` and then `$oldUser`?

Comment: Why is it you are doing this? I'm not sure that it makes sense to run multiple queries inside a scope or to have it return something other than the query.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to use with (a Laravel helper function) and clone.

```
function scopeSomeName($query) {
    with(clone $query)->whereStuff;
    with(clone $query)->whereOtherStuff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you use the same `$query` variable in the two updates. You add `where()`s to the `$query` in the first update query and then run it, but when you add your `where()`s in the second update query the `where()`s from the first query are still there. Because of this your query will return zero result so there is nothing to update. Copy the `$query` first to a new variable then run the second query in the copied one:

```
public function scopeUpdateStatus($query, $oldUser, $newUser, $alias, $env) {
    $queryTemp = $query;

    $query->where('db_conn_app_alias_user', $newUser)
        ->where('db_conn_app_alias', $alias)
        ->where('app_instance_environment', $env)
        ->update(array('user_status' => 'active'));

    $queryTemp->where('db_conn_app_alias_user', $oldUser)
        ->where('db_conn_app_alias', $alias)
        ->where('app_instance_environment', $env)
        ->update(array('user_status' => 'passive'));

    return "success";
}
```

Comment: I attempted this, and it did not seem to work. I ended up just calling the function twice and passing in different parameters to set active or passive.

Comment: @arrowill12 I created a test environment that produced the same problem that you described: only the first update happened. After this change both update happened. Your `DB::update` works because of the same reason. It doesn't use the `$query` so it has a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

A minor edit (reduces overhead) to @merlinpatt answer. You don't need to clone the $query twice. Just once, as you already have the existing/original variable

```
function scopeSomeName($query) {
    $query_cloned = clone $query;
    $query->whereStuff;
    $query_cloned->whereOtherStuff;
}
```

Also, there's no need for the `with()` helper function.
Tested it and works as expected.